# SSIS and Availability group

Tags: ssis

I wonder if someone could help me with a small problem…I’m setting up my server with alwaysOn and I’ve added the SSIS catalog in the availability group. When I failover, it works but I need to run a command to re-encrypt the Master Key on the failover node:

Alter Master Key Add encryption by Service Master Key

I’d like to know is there’s a way to run a command when the secondary node comes online to automate this process…

Comment: I think you may get a better response on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

try using sp_control_dbmasterkey_password on the mirror add the database and password to use.
When the principal switches to mirror it looks through the key storage to find a password to open the db key. Once open, the Service master key auto encrypts.